# how to make an api that gives an image from some custom directory in django rest framework

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-uploads

I am writing the backend code of a website in which there are movies and tv shows. And each film has a poster which can be used on the frontend. these posters are saved in a specific directory folder (let's say "\Posters").

What I need is an API that sends back an image (for example "Jumanji 2017.jpg") using a url like  `.../Poster/Jumanji_2017.jpg` or `.../Poster/Jumanji%202017.jpg`  or anything that would resemble the movie title.

Is there anyway I could do this? (preferably without making an image model)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the `BASE_URL` in which you will save the images as when you *deploy* you could save then on an external bucket (storage) then you can make something like this:

```
class YourModelSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):

image_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = YourModel
    fields = ('some_field', 'some_other_field', 'image_url')

@staticmethod
def get_image_url(obj):
    return BASE_URL + obj.image.url
```

but there is another approach you can use when you don't know or you don't care about the bucket(storage) url where image is saved:

```
class YourModelSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):

image_encoded= serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = YourModel
    fields = ('some_field', 'some_other_field', 'image_encoded')

@staticmethod
def get_image_encoded(obj):
    return base64.b64encode(obj.image)
```

for this one you have to `import base64` and then in your front end you can load image as *base64* like this

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Alt text" />
```

Ps. In the first example `obj.image.url` is the path of the image in the bucket (let it be whatever), but you need the full path to load it on the front end side.